# restore sql backup with microsoft management studio

Tags: sql-server, ssms, restore

I would like to restore an datebase backup file (.BAK) to my ne sqlexpress server.

I make an right click on Database - Restore Database and set all like this:

[image]

[image]

Then I click on OK and I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Make sure to keep the diff. file names for diff. categories.

Comment: sry? this is my first time with management studio and restore backups. what i have to do?#

Comment: ah okay i unterstand - Problem solved ! - thx :)

Comment: What was the problem and how did you resolve it!?